# Spring Boot integration test: Initialize security context

Tags: spring-boot

I have a microservice exposing a REST-API which is secured with OAuth2 using the default Spring Boot configuration in `application.yml`:

```yaml
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      client-id: ...
      client-secret: ...
      grant-type: ...
    resource:
      user-info-uri: ...
      token-info-uri: ...
      prefer-token-info: false
```

The API methods have the usual annotations. The user is authorized in a frontend, which sends authorized requests to the API by sending the token in the header (`Authorization: Bearer ...`).

The user details can then be read in the backend by injecting the `Principal` as an argument in the mapped controller methods, e.g.:

```java
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/foo")
@ContextConfiguration
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public ResponseEntity<List<String>> sampleMethod(Principal user) { // <<- Principal SHOULD NOT BE NULL FOR INTEGRATION TEST
        // some code here
    }
}
```

This works well when running the real microservice. However when running integration tests with `MockMVC` the principal is always `null`:

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@DirtiesContext
class MyControllerIT {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void shouldReturnOk() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/all"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk();
    }

}
```

What is an easy way to set up the `@SpringBootTest` integration test so the security context is pre-populated with some Principal under my control?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the user/principal like:

```
mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/all")).with(user("admin").password("pass").roles("USER","ADMIN")))
```

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/test/mockmvc/authentication.html for all possibilities

Comment: I already tried it like this, but the `principal` reference is still `null`. I tried with `authentication(auth)` and `securityContext(context)` (whereas `auth` and `context` are non-null objects). I also initialized `mockMvc` manually by using `.apply(springSecurity())` as described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/test/mockmvc/setup.html#test-mockmvc-setup)

Comment: `user` post processor populates security-context with `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`, when a `JwtAuthenticationToken` is required here. Use `org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.jwt` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `jwt` post processors for MockMvc request builder. Sample here: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_jwtauthenticationtoken

There is also a dedicated post processor for BearerTokenAuthentication if you are using introspection instead of JWT decoder.

PS
In the répo linked above, you'll find annotations like `@WithMockJwtAuth` that I find more usable than MockMvc requests processors.